# MySQL ERROR 1045 Access Denied

Tags: mysql

I recently installed MySQL on Fedora13. Now, when I try to create a database, it denies me access. I tried resetting the password and it does not recognize my system root. I tried resetting password with an init-file containing:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

I tried uninstall and then reinstall and it is still not working.

I am new to Linux and not comfortable with the filesystem. Talk to me like I'm four.

Thank you, kindly.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else has this problem, I resolved it. At least I think I did. I can log in now and access MySQL.
I removed, erased and reinstalled MySQL several times, along with deleting all the folders I could find that had mysql in them. This did not work. Don't try that.
I finally stumbled upon this procedure, buried in a forum somewhere.

1. Update the packages
2. Type:

   ```
   hostname localhost.localdomain
   mysql_install_db --skip-name-resolve --force
   ```

Done. HTH