# How To Investigate/Restore MySQL Permissions? MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user

Tags: linux, debian, mysql

**ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)**
Debian.

mysqld is listening on 3306 supposedly

Telnet to 3306 works

Also tried binding it specifically yo localhost and then 127.0.0.1 which made no difference

However:

```
# netstat -ln | grep mysql
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     78993    /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# mysql -P3306 -ptest
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Things I've tried:

```
dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.1  Doesn't help
```

http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/442 Doesn't help

This command ([source](https://superuser.com/questions/193817/mysql-error-1045-access-denied)):

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Doesn't help, in fact:

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

So might the user be deleted? Extremely unlikely as all this started after packages update a colleague did and some separate services started screwing around but my colleague said he removed the offenders.

**Theres more**:
while `# mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables` is running one can access the data tables, only with the valid passwords! So there's users and some authentication takes place hence the `0 rows affected` above.

**Can the privileges tables be damaged somehow and how can I recreate/restore them when my only way of getting a mysql console is to skip them?**

Can I spare my reinstall of MySQL? Either way I did get a dump of the DBs now that I  could get in with the above mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically from 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709078/how-can-i-restore-the-mysql-root-users-full-privileges

I went into `# mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables` opened a `# mysql -u root`

Did 
`UPDATE mysql.user SET Grant_priv='Y', Super_priv='Y' WHERE User='root';`

Did a normal `/etc/init.d/mysql start` (after killing the special instance)

Again
`# mysql -u root`

then 
`UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('yrpass') WHERE User='root';`

Root has a pass. Same for the other mysql users where needed.

What I found was there was no privileges/grants at all - regardless of `--skip-grant-tables`.

It was easier with MySQL Workbench to first 
**make root a DBA** as it wasn't.

After that I had to restore the few other users.
Luckily I have a dump of `table_priv` from earlier (before all this) so per table restoration should be fine but that's in my case.

**Also** I had a few root users on `'%'` `'localhost'` `'127.0.0.1'` some of them had an old pass. without having to start a special instance with `--skip-grant-tables` I could get in with the `debian-sys-maint` user, **however** it had a different password because of imports of dumps of other systems! I got that solved by looking at [this article](http://www.happysysadm.com/2011/01/stopping-mysql-database-server-mysqld.html)

What caused all this in the first place I don't know, open for discussion.