# phpmyadmin installation return ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I already have a mysql database in local (installed, configured and containing things for a service).

When I try to install phpmyadmin, I get the following error : `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`.

Here are the steps I do to install phpmyadmin :

- Install phpmyadmin database : Yes
- Socket Unix
- Name of the database : phpmyadmin
- MySQL ID : root@localhost
- MySQL password : mypassword
- MySQL password confirmation : mypassword
- ERROR

The login and password I give to phpmyadmin are the one of the root account for the MySQL service. They work good.

I dont get why phpmyadmin ask for the password if it try to connect to the user without using it (`using password: NO`).

Do you have a solution to force make it using the password ? I can't disable the password of MySQL because the service is accessible by the internet. (And I want to learn a "clean" solution).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How To Investigate/Restore MySQL Permissions? MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user](https://superuser.com/questions/516186/how-to-investigate-restore-mysql-permissions-mysql-error-1045-28000-access-d)

Comment: I just checked the root user in the mysql.user table and all privileges seems good (`Grant_priv` and `Super_priv` are already equal to `Y`). My error seems to come from phpmyadmin attempting to connect to mysql without using the password provided.

Comment: I have exactly same issue.  MySQL has a password setup but phpmyadmin setup refuses to use it.